# ML technique for classification with probability estimates

Tags: java, python, machine-learning, weka, scikit-learn

I want to implement a OCR system. I need my program to not make any mistakes on the letters it does choose to recognize. It doesn't matter if it cannot recognize a lot of them (i.e high precision even with a low recall is Okay).

Can someone help me choose a suitable ML algorithm for this. I've been looking around and find some confusing things. For example, I found contradicting statements about SVM. In the [scikits learn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/svm.html), it was mentioned that we cannot get probability estimates for SVM. Whereas, I found another [post](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?59206-SVM-output-classification-as-probability) that says it is possible to do this in WEKA.

Anyway, I am looking for a machine learning algorithm that best suites this purpose. It would be great if you could suggest a library for the algorithm as well. I prefer Python based solutions, but I am OK to work with Java as well.

Comment: scikit-learn and Weka both actually use the same underlying SVM library, [`libsvm`](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/). This doesn't get *direct* probability estimates (which is what the scikit-learn docs say), but instead solves another learning problem and uses cross-validation to do so, which takes extra time. Section 8 of [this document](http://140.112.30.28/~cjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf) gives details on the algorithm.

Comment: @Dougal So, are these probability estimates reliable or should I go for another Machine Learning technique for these sort of problems?

Comment: Also, how can we get the probability estimate for an unknown sample using cross validation?

Comment: It's not just directly cross-validation; see my link above. My impression is that they're reasonable but not flawless, though I haven't studied their behavior in detail, just used them once or twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* possible to get probability estimates from SVMs in scikit-learn by simply setting `probability=True` when constructing the `SVC` object. The docs only warn that the probability estimates might not be very good.

The quintessential probabilistic classifier is [logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/linear_model.html#logisitic-regression), so you might give that a try. Note that LR is a linear model though, unlike SVMs which can learn complicated non-linear decision boundaries by using kernels.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen people using [neural networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network) with good results, but that was already a few years ago. I asked an expert colleague and he said that nowadays people use things like [nearest-neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_%28pattern_recognition%29) classifiers.

I don't know scikit or WEKA, but any half-decent classification package should have at least k-nearest neighbors implemented. Or you can implement it yourself, it's ridiculously easy. Give that one a try: it will probably have lower precision than you want, however you can make a slight modification where instead of taking a simple majority vote (i.e. the most frequent class among the neighbors wins) you require larger consensus among the neighbors to assign a class (for example, at least 50% of neighbors must be of the same class). The larger the consensus you require, the larger your precision will be, at the expense of recall.

Comment: K-nearest-neighbor classifiers depend a lot on a good distance function between the images, and are bad at generalizing, though in OCR this might not be such a problem. Your consensus idea sounds reasonable, though.